# Any alternative for threadPriority of NSOperation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, nsoperation

@property double **threadPriority** NS_DEPRECATED(10_6, 10_10, 4_0, 8_0);

It showing me deprecated warning and also not working ,I am doing some multi thread stuff and try to set thread priority.

So any alternative for it?

Comment: You can use [qualityOfService](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsoperation/1413553-qualityofservice?language=objc) in combination with [queuePriority](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsoperation/1411204-queuepriority?language=objc) as stated in [here](http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/). Hope this helps you.

Comment: Okay so NSOperation's threadPriority will be auto decided By NSOperationQueue's  NSOperationQueuePriority right?

Comment: I am not an expert, but I feel that's how it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @property double threadPriority NS_DEPRECATED(10_6, 10_10, 4_0, 8_0); is depricated by apple.

Now days Swift async operation Queue and newer threading mechniseus can help to user threding flow as per priorities.